# How do I set up intern.js config to work with local selenium server?

Tags: intern

I need help setting up the intern.js config file to work with a local selenium server. Every time I run the `./node_modules/.bin/intern-runner config=tests/intern`command I get:

```html
Listening on 0.0.0.0:9000
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
  at exports.runInThisContext  <vm.js:53:16>
  at Object.vm.runInThisContext  <node_modules/istanbul/lib/hook.js:174:16>
  at <node_modules/dojo/loader.ts:838:14>
  at tryToString  <fs.js:414:3>
  at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete]  <fs.js:401:12>
```

My selenium server is running on http://127.94.0.1:4444/wd/hub and I do not want to connect to Sauce Labs. Could someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? My intern.js file is below:

```
define({

useSauceConnect: false,
capabilities: {
    'selenium-version': '2.50.1'
},
environments: [
    { browserName: 'chrome' }
],
maxConcurrency: 2,

useSauceConnect: false,


webdriver: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 4444
},

tunnel: 'NullTunnel',

loaderOptions: {
    packages: [ { name: 'myPackage', location: '.' } ]
},

suites: [ /* 'myPackage/tests/foo', 'myPackage/tests/bar' */ ],

functionalSuites: [ 'tests/functional/index' ],

excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:tests|node_modules)\//
```

});

Answer (score 0):

One of your JavaScript files is invalid (incomplete). This isn’t a Selenium problem or a problem with your configuration. Run the Node.js syntax checker against the JavaScript files you’ve written (`node -c <filename>`) and fix the one(s) that are invalid.

Comment: Thanks! I missed a curly brace in one of my test files.